# Vue Router's next(false) clears path on global Navigation Guards

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I found the reason behind my "path flashes", it's `ensureURL` method in the `HTML5History` class (vue-router v3.6.5).

```
// next(false) -> abort navigation, ensure current URL
this.ensureURL(true)
```

If we take a look at this method (that's code from vue-router [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/e3273b3db905f0d162d57725fba0c459ea5bb463/src/history/html5.js#L76))

```
ensureURL (push?: boolean) {
  if (getLocation(this.base) !== this.current.fullPath) {
    const current = cleanPath(this.base + this.current.fullPath)
    push ? pushState(current) : replaceState(current)
  }
}
```

if I try to go straight to the restricted path, at some point, in my app I have `next(false)`, that causes half-second absolutely clear URL.

When I logged vars in this method I noticed that it pushes to `to` url WITH aborting navigation.

[image]

When I commented that `ensureURL(true)` app worked as expected without annoying flashes.

When you try to land on the site with already some sub-path (in my case it was `localhost:8080/broker/login`), you expect url path to stay the same, or redirect you if path is restricted.

Instead once I try to land on the `localhost:8080/broker/login`, after awhile it pushed to `localhost:8080/` then again `localhost:8080/broker/login`.

In my case, there is some logic and async operations on the first website load, that where I have `next(false)`.

After some digging in the vue-router's source code I found `ensureURL` methods that does all that...

If you take a look at this method, you'll see that condition is satisfied

```
getLocation(this.base) !== this.current.fullPath
```

where:

- `getLocation(this.base)` becomes `/broker/login`
- `this.current.fullPath` becomes `/`

so it tries to push to `undefined`

Could you please explain why we need it and how we can fix it?

Comment: Is it still the case with the router v4?

Comment: not sure, we still on Vue 2

Comment: Is it a requirement to be on Vue3?

Comment: Not now, project is huge to migrate